# Safest way to persist logged in state when forced to use basic auth

Tags: security, basic-authentication

Whats the best/safest way to store credentials for subsequent calls to an API using Basic Auth which I dont have control over?

We're apparently only using basic auth for our beta testing phase thankfully, but I have lived long enough to know that sometimes security details get lost on product people and beta users reuse passwords, so want to make it as secure as I can just in case despite it being a temporary thing.

Currently I am using session storage to store credentials in base64 form. Is that really the best that can be done?

Note that in order to get rid of the ugly browser login prompt, the `WWW-Authenticate` header has been removed from the server response. This means that the browser no longer 'magically' caches auth info for subsequent calls, so I need to do it manually somehow.

This what I am currently using. While it technically works, are there ways I can decrease the security risks?

```
const baseUrl = getServerBaseUrl()

const authenticationService = {
  authenticate: (username, password) => {
    const token = btoa(`${username}:${password}`)

    sessionStorage.setItem('credentials', token)

    return axios.get(baseUrl, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${token}`,
      },
    })
  },

  checkAuthentication: () => {
    return axios.get(baseUrl, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${sessionStorage.getItem('credentials')}`,
      },
    })
  },
}
```